# Make a MKAnnotation placemark always visible

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want the placemark (title and subtitle) of a MKAnnotation object to be visible on the mapview at anytime without clicking on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in you map ViewController

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [myMapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
}
```